# How to get User's followers using spotify sdk in flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
String authToken=await getAuthenticationToken();
final response = await http.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/following', headers: {   
  'Authorization': 'Bearer $authToken',
});
print('Token: ${authToken}');
print(response.body);
```

I am getting an error:

> Insufficent client scope

Comment: I think you need to allow access by integrating login: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#:~:text=A%20token%20that%20can%20be,access%20token%20will%20be%20returned.

Comment: I think this one is something similar to your problem: https://github.com/rckclmbr/pyportify/issues/60.